How to make AppArmor rule to prevent delete in specific directory for all apps instead of specific app?
I want to deny delete permission to everything that is in /home/don/testdir or it's sub directories for all apps without preventing create or write. As I understood this is not possible with conventional ACL because write permission is either all (create+write+delete) or nothing, I can't deny just delete while allowing to create and write.
I have tried chattr +a for that directory but if after running this command  sub directory is added and in that sub directory file is added, it does not prevent removal of that file for example testdir/subdir/file.txt.
I am new to AppArmor. I tried to create the following rule and save it as /etc/apparmor.d/home.don.testdir but it did not work
# Profile to prevent any process from deleting files in /home/don/testdir

profile prevent-delete {
    # Allow read, write, and execute within the directory
    /home/don/testdir/ rix,
    /home/don/testdir/** rwlix,

    # Explicitly deny delete operations
    deny /home/don/testdir/** D,
}

I got AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/home.don.testdir in profile /etc/apparmor.d/home.don.testdir at line 9: syntax error, unexpected TOK_ID, expecting TOK_MODE.

D is not a known access mode and therefore is invalid.  That's why your rule does not parse properly.
Additionally, AppArmor does not have a concept of "deny delete" from my reading of the manpages on its policy system.

You may want to refer to the AppArmor manpage on policy structure (see https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/noble/man5/apparmor.d.5.html which is the 24.04 manpage for how AppArmor profiles are set up) to learn how things work in AppArmor policies..
These're the access modes known by AppArmor (I've trimmed most of the data out that isn't relevant to your question), and what deny can accept as access modes:
Access Modes Details
       r - Read mode
           Allows the program to have read access to the file or directory listing. Read access
           is required for shell scripts and other interpreted content.

       w - Write mode
           Allows the program to have write access to the file. Files and directories must have
           this permission if they are to be unlinked (removed.)  Write mode is not required on a
           directory to rename or create files within the directory.

           This mode conflicts with append mode.

       a - Append mode
           Allows the program to have a limited appending only write access to the file.  Append
           mode will prevent an application from opening the file for write unless it passes the
           O_APPEND parameter flag on open.

           The mode conflicts with Write mode.

       ux - Unconfined execute mode

       Ux - unconfined execute -- scrub the environment

       px - Discrete Profile execute mode

       Px - Discrete Profile execute mode -- scrub the environment

       cx - Transition to Subprofile execute mode

       Cx - Transition to Subprofile execute mode -- scrub the environment

       ix - Inherit execute mode

The closest you would get to a "no delete" mode is by allowing append mode and disallowing write mode as write mode includes the ability to delete.
However, this may break your applications using those files because not all applications call the open or similar syscalls with the APPEND option enabled.
